# HTTP status code for in progress?

Tags: http, rest

I have an endpoint that looks something like this:
GET:
/v1/resourcebeingcreated/status

Is there a preferred HTTP status code to return (beyond 200 with a response body that explains "in progress") if the loading/creation of this resource is in progress but not complete?

If not, is the best way to return the "in progress" status in a header or the response body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success -
   no. :)
2. I think it should depend on what you are trying to
   achieve. Is it that you trying to notify a third party somehow? If
   you are defining your own API, that would be OK I guess to set it in
   the header. Yet, a more common and more intuitive approach is the
   body.

Comment: That is what I figured, and yes this is to notify a third party of progress of a particular resource... I will probably just return the info in the body like you mentioned. BTW Your grumpy cat avatar is AWESOME!